# Streams equivalent to Observable.Throttle?

Tags: dart, dart-async

Is there a Streams equivalent to [Observable.Throttle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229298%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)?  If not -- is there any reasonably elegant way to achieve a similar effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [rate_limit package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rate_limit) provides throttling and debouncing of Streams.

Comment: Not compatible with Dart 2.

Answer (score 5):

There's no such method on streams for now. A enhancement request has been filed, you can star [issue 8492](http://dartbug.com/8492).

However, you can do that with the [where](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_async/Stream.html#where) method. In the following exemple, I have defined a `ThrottleFilter` class to ignore events during a given duration :

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class ThrottleFilter<T> {
  DateTime lastEventDateTime = null;
  final Duration duration;

  ThrottleFilter(this.duration);

  bool call(T e) {
    final now = new DateTime.now();
    if (lastEventDateTime == null ||
        now.difference(lastEventDateTime) > duration) {
      lastEventDateTime = now;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

main() {
  final sc = new StreamController<int>();
  final stream = sc.stream;

  // filter stream with ThrottleFilter
  stream.where(new ThrottleFilter<int>(const Duration(seconds: 10)).call)
    .listen(print);

  // send ints to stream every second, but ThrottleFilter will give only one int
  // every 10 sec.
  int i = 0;
  new Timer.repeating(const Duration(seconds:1), (t) { sc.add(i++); });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following version is closer to what Observable.Throttle does:

```dart
class Throttle extends StreamEventTransformer {
  final duration;
  Timer lastTimer;

  Throttle(millis) :
    duration = new Duration(milliseconds : millis);


  void handleData(event, EventSink<int> sink) {
    if(lastTimer != null){
      lastTimer.cancel();
    }
    lastTimer = new Timer(duration, () => sink.add(event));
  }
}

main(){
  //...
  stream.transform(new Throttle(500)).listen((_) => print(_));
  //..
}
```

Comment: This might be outdated as `StreamEventTransformer` is no longer a valid class in Dart

Answer (score 2):

@Victor Savkin's answer is nice, but I always try to avoid reinventing the wheel. So unless you really only need that throttle I'd suggest using the [RxDart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) package. Since you are dealing with Streams and other reactive objects [RxDart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) has a lot of nice goodies to offer besides throttling.

We can achieve a 500 millisecond throttle several ways:

1. [throttleTime](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/ThrottleExtensions/throttleTime.html) from `ThrottleExtensions<T>` `Stream<T>` extensions: `stream.throttleTime(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).listen(print);`
2. Combining [ThrottleStreamTransformer](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/ThrottleStreamTransformer-class.html) with [TimerStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/TimerStream-class.html): `stream.transform(ThrottleStreamTransformer((_) => TimerStream(true, const Duration(milliseconds: 500)))).listen(print);`
3. Using [Debounce Extensions](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/DebounceExtensions.html) / [DebounceStreamTransformer](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/DebounceStreamTransformer-class.html): `stream.debounceTime(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).listen(print);`

There are some subtle differences regarding delays, but all of them throttles. As an example about `throttleTime` vs. `debounceTime` see [What is the difference between throttleTime vs debounceTime in RxJS and when to choose which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460436/what-is-the-difference-between-throttletime-vs-debouncetime-in-rxjs-and-when-to)

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 solutions that do not require additional packages:

### 1. Extension Method

```
import 'dart.async';

extension StreamMethods<T> on Stream<T> {
  Stream<T> throttle(Duration duration) {
    T? lastEvent;
    Timer? throttleTimer;
    StreamController<T> resultStreamController = StreamController<T>();
    
    listen((event) {
      lastEvent = event;
      throttleTimer ??= Timer(
        duration,
        () {
          throttleTimer = null;
          if (lastEvent != null) {
            resultStreamController.add(lastEvent!);
            lastEvent = null;
          }
        },
      );
    });

    return resultStreamController.stream;
  }
}

void main() {
  // this will output an 20 events every second: 1, 2, 3, ...
  final stream = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => i + 1).take(20);
  
  // this will throttle events every 3 seconds: 4, 8, 12, ...
  stream.throttle(Duration(seconds: 3)).listen(print);
}
```

### 2. Implementing `StreamTransformer`

I believe this would be an up-to-date version of @Victor Savkin's answer:

```
import 'dart:async';

class Throttle<S, T> implements StreamTransformer<S, T> {
  final _resultStreamController = StreamController<T>();
  Timer? throttleTimer;
  Duration duration;
  
  Throttle(this.duration);
  
  @override
  Stream<T> bind(Stream<S> stream) {
    S? lastEvent;
    
    stream.listen((event) {
      lastEvent = event;
      throttleTimer ??= Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 3),
        () {
          throttleTimer = null;
          if (lastEvent != null) {
            _resultStreamController.add(lastEvent! as T);
            lastEvent = null;
          }
        },
      );
    });
    
    return _resultStreamController.stream;
  }
  
  @override
  StreamTransformer<RS, RT> cast<RS, RT>() {
    return StreamTransformer.castFrom(this);
  }
}

void main() {
  // this will output an 20 events every second: 1, 2, 3, ...
  final stream = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => i + 1).take(20);

  // this will throttle events every 3 seconds: 4, 8, 12, ...
  stream.transform(Throttle(Duration(seconds: 3))).listen(print);
}
```