# What is the difference between throttleTime vs debounceTime in RxJS and when to choose which?

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm trying to understand `throttleTime` vs `debounceTime` and which one is to be used when?

I have an upvote button that makes an API request to the backend (which counts the votes). User can submit button multiple times, but I'd like to limit the times per second button can be pressed.

I know `throttleTime` and `debounceTime` operators can do that, but which one should I choose?

```js
const upvoteClicks = fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'click')
   .pipe(debounceTime(500))
   .subscribe(() => this.myService.postUpvote(this.postId));
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I think in your case `throttleTime` works a little bit better, because you want to make the api request as soon as user clicks the button.

Both `throttleTime` and `debounceTime` ignore the events which come in the meantime, but `throttleTime` emits right away, while
`debounceTime` waits for additional delay.

You can visually see that very well at https://rxmarbles.com
[image]

[image]

What is more, [throttleTime vs debounceTime in RxJS](https://namitamalik.github.io/throttleTime-vs-debounceTime-in-RxJS/) article provides a good overview of both operators.

Answer (score 12):

***(A more simple answer)***

Say a user clicks a button that triggers a request (example):

**Throttle time** = can limit the number of clicks so only 1 goes through every second (prevents button spamming)

**Debounce time** = can add a delay before each request goes through (you press the button then nothing happens for 1 seconds, *then* your request goes through)

1 second was just an example. You can enter whatever you'd in the debounceTime() or throttleTime() - in ms

Comment: While this is correct, you only explain the 'when' and not 'what'. In OP's example the button press represents a like or vote. Let's say the user voted on a 1st post and immediately changed his mind and voted for the 2nd post/person/whatever. Using `throttleTime` you'd register a like for post 1 and using `debounceTime` you'd register a like for post 2. Neither implementation is superior to the other, but it's an important difference to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer has clearly pointed out the difference between `throttleTime` and `debounceTime`.

However I'd like to bring up a slightly different option in your particular situation, that is `exhaustMap`.  `exhaustMap` is an operator that ignores every new projected Observable if the previous one has not yet completed. So the first API request to backend has to be completed before the user can execute it the second time. It's useful if the API data is bouncing back very slowly, slower than the fixed time you set, it won't trigger any further API call until the previous one completed.
[You can read more about exhaustMap here](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/exhaustMap).

```
const upvoteClicks = fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'click')
   .pipe(
      exhaustMap(() => this.myService.postUpvote(this.postId))
    )
   .subscribe(() => console.log('upvoted!'))
```